# Servo acting weird

Tags: arduino

Arduino Nano, Servo SG-90, +9 V PP3 battery, stabilizer +6V L7806

Stabilizer has two outputs: **2.** +9 V directly from the battery, **1.** +6 V

**B.** is Voltage in for Arduino
**A.** is Voltage in for Servo

[image: circuit]

First it was connected like: **2 -> A, 2 -> B** 
This option works great. But I'm afraid to burn the servo, though the load it is episodic. (Loads last for 0.1 second not more than once per second)

If I connects via stabilizer: **1 -> A, 2 -> B** 
Servo goes crazy - goes from 0 to 180 and back infinitely. Arduino board is operating normally.

I tried option **1 -> A, 1 -> B** - in this embodiment, servo emits strange sounds, Arduino does not work. 
Option **1 -> B, 2 -> A**  works perfectly, but it defeats the purpose of the stabilizer, the servo is still +9V

Questions:

1. What's going on and how to fix it? I'd like to use **1 -> A, 2 -> B**
2. Is it possible to feed servo from +9V. If it does not work all the time, it may work normal?

Comment: ANSWER: L78L00 i've used had a currency limitation. Replaced with more powerful analog and all worked OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L78L00 i've used had a currency limitation. Replaced with more powerful analog and all worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

First step: Are all your grounds connected together?  They must be all connected together for any of this stuff to work.  If you have each ground separated from each other, that's the probable cause.

Second step: All your grounds are connected, but still wild -- hook up a voltmeter to connection point 1 and verify if a stable 6V coming out.  If it's bouncing up & down, you've got your answer.